# data missing from string with multiple colon

Tags: flashdevelop

Try this, and you'll notice the 1st data with the colon is missing. why & how to solve this?

```
trace("1"+":"+"2"+":"+"3"+":"+"4")
```

Comment: it's ok if you have 'space' inside the colon string though. ok maybe this just happens in flashdevelop :(

Comment: Yep, FD uses it for output coloring. Try to use different numbers instead of 1, like 2, 3, 4 at the beginning and you'll notice that the the traced text changes colour. Although I did not find a way to override this behaviour.

Comment: it does not matter what numbers I put in front, it will not show the 1st data.

Comment: That's what I said: you can use any number in this manner and it will be ignored, because FD uses this number for text colouring. Is there no other way to output the code you want, like adding a space at the beginning of the string?

Comment: though i would like to avoid that, but seems that that's the only solution now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @package, put your comment as the answer so it can be accepted. Hwang - you might think it's awkward, but it's incredibly handy if you're developing a logging system, as it lets you class logs (error, warning, info, debug, "i love mammy" messages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FlashDevelop's Output panel matches the first number followed by colons (ie. /^[0-9]:/) for output coloring. Different numbers will color the lines with different colors.

There is currently no way to prevent this behavior, however the information traced is still there and you can see it entirely using FlashDevelop LogViewer (see Tools menu) instead.